# If a supplier offers commission to a purchaser, is it halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

I am working in company as an admin officer in UAE. Our company has 15 vehicles. I have to make insurance for all vehicles which is mandatory in U.A.E. The two insurance companies offered me same rates for making insurance. It is my will to give business to any of them. One insurance company is willing to give me some commission. Is it haram to take commission from insurance company?

Comment: That's just a thinly disguised bribe.

Comment: Related: [Is it halal to give commission or gifts to clients to get contracts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11275/17163)

Answer (score 3):

The rule is very simple: if you were to stay in your residence and not have your current job, would you have received said commission either way? If the answer is yes, you can take it. If the answer is no (which will almost always be the case), then you are not allowed to take it. The Prophet ﷺ said:

> عَنْ أَبِي حُمَيْدٍ السَّاعِدِيِّ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ اسْتَعْمَلَ النَّبِيُّ ﷺ رَجُلاً مِنَ الأَزْدِ يُقَالُ لَهُ ابْنُ اللُّتْبِيَّةِ عَلَى الصَّدَقَةِ، فَلَمَّا قَدِمَ قَالَ: هَذَا لَكُمْ، وَهَذَا أُهْدِيَ لِي‏.‏ قَالَ:‏ فَهَلاَّ جَلَسَ فِي بَيْتِ أَبِيهِ أَوْ بَيْتِ أُمِّهِ، فَيَنْظُرَ يُهْدَى لَهُ أَمْ لاَ وَالَّذِي نَفْسِي بِيَدِهِ لاَ يَأْخُذُ أَحَدٌ مِنْهُ شَيْئًا إِلاَّ جَاءَ بِهِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ يَحْمِلُهُ عَلَى رَقَبَتِهِ، إِنْ كَانَ بَعِيرًا لَهُ رُغَاءٌ أَوْ بَقَرَةً لَهَا خُوَارٌ أَوْ شَاةً تَيْعَرُ ـ ثُمَّ رَفَعَ بِيَدِهِ، حَتَّى رَأَيْنَا عُفْرَةَ إِبْطَيْهِ ـ اللَّهُمَّ هَلْ بَلَّغْتُ اللَّهُمَّ هَلْ بَلَّغْتُ ثَلاَثًا
>
> Narrated Abu Humaid Al-Sa'idi: The Prophet ﷺ appointed a man from the tribe of Al-Azd, called Ibn 'Utbiyya for collecting the Zakat. When he returned he said, "This (i.e. the Zakat) is for you and this has been given to my as a present." The Prophet ﷺ said, "Why hadn't he stayed in his father's or mother's house to see whether he would be given presents or not? By Him in Whose Hands my life is, whoever takes something from the resources of the Zakat (unlawfully) will be carrying it on his neck on the Day of Resurrection; if it be a camel, it will be grunting; if a cow, it will be mooing; and if a sheep, it will be bleating." The Prophet then raised his hands till we saw the whiteness of his armpits, and he said thrice, "O Allah! Haven't I conveyed Your Message (to them)?"
>
> <sub>— [Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 51, Hadith 31](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/31)</sub>

The Prophet ﷺ explained that anything one takes beyond one's contracted compensation is a form of *ghulūl* (embezzlement):

> عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ بُرَيْدَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ ﷺ قَالَ: مَنِ اسْتَعْمَلْنَاهُ عَلَى عَمَلٍ فَرَزَقْنَاهُ رِزْقًا فَمَا أَخَذَ بَعْدَ ذَلِكَ فَهُوَ غُلُولٌ
>
> Narrated Buraidah: The Prophet ﷺ as saying: When we appoint someone to an administrative post and provide him with an allowance, anything he takes beyond that is unfaithful dealing.
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud, Book 20, Hadith 16](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/20/16)</sub>

*Ghulūl* is strictly prohibited in Islam, with tidings of punishments in both this life and the hereafter:

> عَنْ عُبَادَةَ بْنِ اَلصَّامِتِ ‏- رضى الله عنه ‏- قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ‏ﷺ: لَا تَغُلُّوا فَإِنَّ اَلْغُلُولَ نَارٌ وَعَارٌ عَلَى أَصْحَابِهِ فِي اَلدُّنْيَا وَالْآخِرَةِ
>
> 'Ubadah bin as-Samit (RAA) narrated that The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: "Do not be dishonest (and treacherous) about the war booty (i.e. steal from it before it is divided legally), as Ghulul will be like fire (for the ones who got involved in it) and a cause of disgrace to those who are guilty of it in this world and in the Hereafter."
>
> <sub>— [Bulugh al-Maram, Book 11, Hadith 1318](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/2115730)</sub>

Based on the above, scholars have decreed that taking any form of gifts from people that one deals with at work, in a business-like relationship, based on their position is forbidden.