# Am I allowed to take commission from a supplier when my boss doesn't know?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

I am a buyer for a company and I have asked for a raise, but received nothing.  I have a supplier that has come to sell products to me for the company, and he said he will give me a commission, but will sell at same price. Am I allowed to take this money when my boss doesn't know? And if not, how wrong is it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please specify that to which company does the supplier belongs i.e to your employer's or some other company. and the commission to you will be given by the supplier or from the income of the company. And whether you will be selling the supplier's items to your own company or to someone else.

Comment: Relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/if-a-supplier-offers-commission-to-a-purchaser-is-it-halal

Answer (score 1):

Giving Nominal Appraisal is your Boss duties. if he is muslim , convey him the hadith about giving salary to the employee before sweat getting drained.

otherwise, you should inform your owner about commission because it doesn't spoil his business so he may accept it. but you should inform him . because there is one hadith but i dont know where it is,

> "prophet mohammed appointed a sahabi as a governor in particular
>   place, he got gift because of his post. this issue reached prophet,
>   prophet said, you getting these gifts only because you're in power
>   else people wont give you those. so, surrender your gift into
>   management. if you got permission you can take from  that."

if anyone knew this hadith number please share.

> **It has been narrated on the authority of Abu Humaid as-Sa'idi who said:**
>   The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) appointed a man from the Asad tribe who was called Ibn Lutbiyya in charge of Sadaqa (i. e. authorised hign to receive Sadaqa from the people on behalf of the State. When he returned (with the collictions), he said: This is for you and (this is mine as) it was presented to me as a gift. The narrator said: The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upod him) stood on the pulpit and praised God and extolled Him. Then he said: What about a State official whom I give an assignment and who (comes and) says: This is for you and this has been presented to me as a gift? Why didn't he remain in the house of his father or the house of his mother so that he could observe whether gifts were presented to him or not. By the Being in Whose Hand is the life of Muhammad, any one of you will not take anything from it but will bring it on the Day of Judgment, carrying on his neck a camel that will be growling, or a cow that will be bellowing or an ewe that will be bleating. Then he raised his hands so that we could see the whiteness of his armpits. Then he said twice: O God, I have conveyed (Thy Commandments). ([Source](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/37))

```
Reference    : Sahih Muslim 1832 a
In-book reference    : Book 33, Hadith 37
USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 20, Hadith 4509
```

Comment: search "gift" with ctrl+f in https://sunnah.com/muslim/33 .

Comment: jazakallah kair @qdinar .. i remember this hadees but i dono where it is present.. jazakallah kair i got it... edited my answer supported with hadeed